# What causes air bubbles/air glugs when getting blood drawn with a vacutainer system?

Tags: blood, blood-tests, blood-donation, test-results

As I understand it, the vacutainer system used in modern phlebotomy should never result in air bubbles “glugging” into the vacutainer tube when blood is drawn from a patient.

However, today I learned that it does happen because it happened while my blood was being drawn. I was so surprised I didn’t know what to say. I’ve had my blood drawn many times and never experienced it. What are the circumstances in which this could occur? I also assume that the movement of air which causes the gurgling is air entering the vacutainer tube, not leaving it. Is there a circumstance in which air could leave the tube and enter the bloodstream during the blood draw?

I found a couple of articles — first is about results being skewed due to gas entering blood samples in pneumatic tube based: [Air bubbles and hemolysis of blood samples during transport by pneumatic tube systems](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/28803746/)

Second article was about venous air embolism, which can also occur very rarely when blood is drawn. Historically this would be when it’s done with a needle and syringe — the point of the vacutainer system is that it should not be possible for air to enter the blood stream because the vial has a vacuum in it that “sucks” the blood out.

Interestingly, in my case, the glugging occurred with the first vial — I had two vials drawn — but the second vial filled as normal. So I’m wondering if the vacutainer system can fail in unexpected ways.

I suppose there’s also the Rumsfeldian “failure of imagination” scenario where one could pressurize a vacutainer tube with a gas and force the gas into someone’s bloodstream, but that’s clearly off topic. I’m more interested in the safety and efficacy of the vacutainer system in general and/or if blood test results can become unreliable even with the vacutainer system.

Comment: I would suspect one of two possibilities: the phlebotomist made an error or it was a  defective tube, and I always rank pilot error as the most likely cause. The error I imagine might have been made was not attaching the Vacutainer to the catheter tightly, so it was able to suck air through the loose coupling.

Comment: What sort of defect in the tube are you thinking of?

Comment: I have no idea; it's just that a product defect always has to be on the list of possibilities. But I doubt that's the explanation. As I said, pilot error is the most likely explanation.

Comment: I could imagine either some variation in angle of attack at the vacutainer / tube connection (there's a little wiggle room) or at the needle / patient connection (pulling the needle back to allow air and blood into the tube). But, yes, product defect cannot be ruled out; the tube stopper could allow air to be sucked in with minor manipulation. The effects of outside air depend on the test being performed - likely best to obtain an additional sample and discard the contaminated sample when this happens.